# Attach data to a dom node in ejs template

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am using the ejs templating engine from https://ejs.co/
Is it possible to attach some data to a dom element inside the template?
Something like

```
const thing1 = function() {alert('hello!');};
const thing2 = 'ciao!';
let things = [thing1, thing2];
let template = `
<ul>
<% for(let i=0; i<things.length; i++) { %>
  <li data-thing="<%???? things[i] %>">i</li>
<% } %>
</ul>
`

$('body').html(ejs.render(template, things));

//get the object stored on the dom element:
$($('li')[0]).data('thing');
```

Comment: Yes, it is. What doesn't work?

Comment: You aren't using `template` at all? Maybe you want `ejs.render(template, { things })` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms, yes sorry my code was wrong. Corrected. The thing that does not work is that I don't know how to store a javascript object on a dom node inside an ejs template.

Comment: You can't. And you should not.

Comment: @JonasWilms care to elaborate why?

Comment: HTML is a data encoding after all. DOM nodes can only contain strings (with a few exceptions for some special properties)